# Centering Inline-Blocks

Tags: css

I have been working all night to center two inline-blocks, but I can't seem to do it. The frame either incredibly offsets the page, or just stays stuck on the left. I have tried centering the text (which would center everything else) and setting the left & margin-left via CSS. Can't figure out a good solution. The divs with the class of "box" need to be centered, there are two of them.

My code is on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x872fb38/), any help is appreciated.

```
div#signin-reg {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   position: absolute;
}
div.box {
    padding: 2.5px;
    float: middle;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 230px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #dfdfdf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

This is what it looks like now[image]
What I want it to look like (rough, just edited in Preview)[image]

Comment: Which element to be centered ?

Comment: Can you provide some kind of a screenshot showing us which elements should be centered?

Comment: Do you want the #signin-reg to be centered or the two .boxes in it?

Comment: @Sirence the two .box elements

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/x872fb38/6/

```
div#signin-reg {
   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

  div.box {
      padding: 2.5px;
      float: middle;
      vertical-align: top;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 230px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #dfdfdf;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #dfdfdf;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to use text-align: center because I don't want the text to be centered, but it does center everything else nicely.

Comment: Just add text-align: left to the .box.

Comment: `middle` is not a valid value for `float`

Answer (score 2):

Remove from `#signin-reg` `position:absolute`. Set width which is `.box` + `.box` and add `margin: 0 auto`.

`width: 475px; margin: 0 auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/x872fb38/3/

I played with it a bit and managed to code it like in the screenshots. 
Here's the demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/x872fb38/5/

Though I have some things I'd like to say. If I were you I would use [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/). 
Using this framework what you want to achieve is pretty easy & there are lots of examples on the Internet.

However, if you want to code it yourself or using a framework would be an overkill, here's my approach:

I will set to `.box` - `float: left` and will remove `display: inline-block;` this will align them next to each other as long as there's space. Here we solve the issue with lower resolutions ("responsiveness"). If the width of your document is less than the required width for the two `.box` to align horizontally then one of the will go below. This requires the parent element to be with `width` set in percentages.

Anyways, if you are not that pretentious, the demo above will do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `positon:absolute` from the `div#signin-reg`

```
 div#signin-reg {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x872fb38/4/)

Answer (score 0):

the other answers are ok,

but, if for some specific reason, you need absolute positioning,
you can do this:

```
div#signin-reg {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```